# Upgrading 4.6.14 LTS Upgrade

Tags: upgrade, lts

Current system:
Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8
Wordpress 4.4.2
PHP 5.5
MySQL 5.1.73

I am currently running CiviCRM 4.6.14 on a live system on which our users have found a problem when ordering custom date fields.  This ordering issue does seem to be resolved in the latest version so I need to upgrade.
I can upgrade to the latest LTS (4.6.36) without a problem but this does not resolve the issue and moving away from the LTS is proving difficult. 
I have tried upgrading to 5.0.1 and receive a HTTP 500 error after clicking the 'Return to homepage' link once the upgrade is complete.
I then restored my server snapshot take after the successful 4.6.36 upgrade and tried 4.7.31 as this was the stable version released at the same time as the LTS version I can update to.  Again, HTTP 500 error after the upgrade.

No errors are shown during the upgrade which is reported as successful.

Am I missing instructions somewhere for migrating out of the LTS branch or can someone help with the error please?
My CiviCRM lof file is here: https://pastebin.com/Hw8qhmNN

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Russell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking Civi log it seems that problem is with civicrm_uf_group.frontend_title field. I would suggest you to do incremental upgrade i.e

Upgrade CiviCRM to 4.6.x to 4.7.30
Upgrade CiviCRM to 4.7.31.

> On a separate note make sure you disable all the CiviCRM extension or
>   wp plugin and also disable wp post or pages that have CiviCRM profile
>   shortcode before upgrading.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: disable logging too perhaps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of disabling the CiviCRM extensions - disabling the 'CiviCRM Postcode Lookup' extension completes the update and successfully launches CiviCRM.

I now have an issue of custom data not displaying when the Tab is set as 'Tab with Table'. I'll investigate further and post a new topic if required.